# App Crashing when clicking on list preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference, edittextpreference

I am currently in the process of adding a Preferences/Settings activity to my app. I keep running into a problem though. The `preference.xml` file loads fine but as soon as I try to click either a list preference or an `Edit Text` preference it crashes the activity with the following stack trace:

```
10-06 11:11:20.464 16629-16629/com.example.benhouse.weatherview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.benhouse.weatherview, PID: 16629
                                                                              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/dialog_background_material.xml from color state list resource ID #0x108026d
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2750)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2699)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:439)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3777)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3981)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:383)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:233)
                                                                                  at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
                                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
                                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
                                                                                  at android.preference.DialogPreference.showDialog(DialogPreference.java:319)
                                                                                  at android.preference.DialogPreference.onClick(DialogPreference.java:277)
                                                                                  at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:994)
                                                                                  at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:214)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                               Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid color state list tag inset
                                                                                  at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:217)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:201)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2746)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2699) 
                                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:439) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3777) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3981) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:383) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:233) 
                                                                                  at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295) 
                                                                                  at android.preference.DialogPreference.showDialog(DialogPreference.java:319) 
                                                                                  at android.preference.DialogPreference.onClick(DialogPreference.java:277) 
                                                                                  at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:994) 
                                                                                  at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:214) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042) 
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It looks like the crash is being caused by `dialog_background_material.xml` not being present but looking through countless examples none mention needing to add such a file so I presume it is a file either the sdk or gradle is supposed to add.

Here is my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.benhouse.weatherview"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And my `prefFragment`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
    }

}
```

`preference.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="PreferenceCategory A">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="checkbox_preference"
            android:title="title_checkbox_preference"
            android:summary="summary_checkbox_preference" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="PreferenceCategory B">

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="edittext_preference"
            android:title="title_edittext_preference"
            android:summary="summary_edittext_preference"
            android:dialogTitle="dialog_title_edittext_preference" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="ListPreference">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="list_preference"
            android:title="title_list_preference"
            android:summary="summary_list_preference"
            android:entries="@array/listDisplayWord"
            android:entryValues="@array/listReturnValue"
            android:dialogTitle="dialog_title_list_preference" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

I am really stumped on this as I have looked through so many examples and questions and none mention such an issue and use similar code to get their screen working.

Comment: are you using MaterialDialog

Comment: I don't know whether I am or not. Should I be?

Comment: Cause the error doesn't seem to be related to Preference activity.

Comment: what if you change compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0' to compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'?

Comment: just tried that now and I still get the same stack trace error.

Comment: Thanks... Yall are real helpful... problem not solved.

Comment: I am curious to know what helped you? if you found the answer you should answer your own question.

Comment: I didn't... No one else posted anything so I couldn't figure it out. If I could have figured it out on my own I wouldn't have bothered to post in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by switching to `android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceFragment` in the Android support library. Note that you might need to change other classes to their support library variant as well.